# Is it possible to add a callback URL to Create Google Account flow?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Our app requires Google OAuth2. When a user, with an existing Google account, authenticates with Google then we use a callback to return users to our App. This is what we want.

The issue is, for those users who do not have a Google account we ask them to create a Google account (gmail address) or [connect their existing email address](https://accounts.google.com/SignUpWithoutGmail) to Google. A user who has to follow either of these flows ends up on the "Thanks for creating a Google account page" and not back at our App.

Answer (score 0):

This is supposed to work as you are expecting. There is a continue button on that page and that should bring the user back.
If that is not working, can you tell us more (about OS, client id, urls and the exact steps) or give us a link to test/reproduce? Is this on the web or on mobile app?